# How to add multiple checkbox selected value in listview in Android

Tags: android, listview

I have multiple checkbox with listview but whenever i am trying to add get selected value of checkbox to listview it only set the last selected value to the listview. I want to set all selected value of checkbox to the new listview

Comment: just post your code how you tried

Comment: Please post your code first

Answer (score 0):

Anyway this may help you to get the selected items from the multi select listview

```
SparseBooleanArray checked = tags.getCheckedItemPositions();
    for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
        if(checked.valueAt(i) == true) {
            Tag tag = (Tag) tags.getItemAtPosition(checked.keyAt(i));
            Log.i("xxxx", i + " " + tag);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this library .It works good and suits your need
[MultiSelectSpinner](https://github.com/prsidhu/MultiSelectSpinner)